# How to compare two urls when the run time url generates dynamic id

Tags: java, regex, selenium

I am learning automation. I am not able two compare to urls in which the dynamic ids get generated every run.

first url:
https://open.login.yahoo.com/openid/yrp/signin?idp=facebook&ts=1393975202&.intl=us&.lang=en-US&.done=http%3A%2F%2Fmail.yahoo.com&rpcrumb=ZJMkr60PLSv&.src=ym

comparing with runtime url where ids gets dynamically generated
first at idp=facebook&ts=139xxx
second at &rpcrumb=xxx

Please help

Comment: Comparing URLs is messy-to-impossible for anyone but the server responding to that URL, since there are so many ways of expressing "the same" URL and there may be many URLs pointing to the same content. Most code that I've seen simply gives up and settles for simple string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

If that is the only difference, you can just remove these 2 attributes from both urls before comparing:

```
String url1 = url1.replaceFirst("ts=[^&]*&", "").replaceFirst("rpcrumb =[^&]*&", "");

String url1 = url2.replaceFirst("ts=[^&]*&", "").replaceFirst("rpcrumb =[^&]*&", "");

// now compare
if (url1.equalsIgnoreCase(url2)) {...}
```